I have two identical wi-fi drivers installed?
If you run the "dkms status" command in Ubuntu, two identical lines are returned. Here they are::

rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 6.5.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821ce/v5.5.2_34066.20200325, 6.5.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed

Does this mean that I have two identical rtl8821ce drivers installed ?
And how can I disable one driver here if they have the same name ?

you have two kernels installed. if you don't face any problem with the wifi, don't do anything.

Thanks for the answer. I just encountered the problem :: unstable download speed via Wi-Fi. Sometimes the download speed is 1 megabyte, sometimes the download speed is 30 megabytes. Stable Wi-Fi was on the kernel 6.5.0-28. Are there any ideas for solving the Wi-Fi problem?

They belong to different kernel versions (6.5.0-44 and 6.5.0-41). It is a good idea to keep multiple kernel version installed (Ubuntu already does that), because otherwise, a faulty kernel update may render your computer unusable.
If there are too many old kernel versions, run sudo apt autoremove to remove all except the current and the previous kernel version.

Thanks for the reply. When I had kernel 6.5.0-28::: I had stable download speed via wi-fi. Now, sometimes download speed via wi-fi is 1-4 megabytes, sometimes 20-30 megabytes. Any ideas on how to solve the problem with wi-fi?

You can access older kernels from the grub boot menu. Here is how to do that https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time. However, the kernel is mentioned is quite old. In case that has been removed, I am unsure how to restore it. Please ask a new question in that case. Maybe, upgrading the kernel to a later version like 6.8 may also help (but, please ask a new question. Don't try to upgrade the kernel yourself as that may break many things).

Archisman Panigrahi, thanks for the help
